# Appending elements to list and removing from another

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
lst=[201, 303, 210, 407, 213, 313]
lst2=[302,304,404]
value=4
for j in range(0,len(lst),-1):
        if len(lst)>=value:
            lst2.append(lst[j])
```

I'm trying to append the last 4 elements in "lst" to "lst2", its 4 because that is what i assigned to `value`. However, nothing in the lists change?

Comment: `list(range(0, 6, -1))` ? Why are you using a step of -1?

Comment: Not clear where the "removing from another" part applies here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is `range(start, stop, step)`. As such, iterating over `range(0, len(lst), -1)` will iterative over *nothing* as you can't step *down* from `0` to a positive number.

This would work, noting we must subtract 1 to account for 0-indexing:

```
for j in range(len(lst)-1, len(lst)-1-value, -1):
    lst2.append(lst[j])

print(lst2)

[302, 304, 404, 313, 213, 407, 210]
```

Your `range` object here is a bit convoluted. Noting that negative ranges and negative list indexing work fine, you can use instead `range(-1, -value-1, -1)`.

With Python, you don't need to loop over ranges at all here. Instead, you can use list slicing and [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) to iterate the values themselves rather than indices:

```
for j in reversed(lst[-value:]):
    lst2.append(j)
```

Of course, a manual loop is not required here, you can extend via `+=`:

```
lst2 += reversed(lst[-value:])
```

If you *also* need to remove these items from `lst`, you can do so via slicing:

```
lst = lst[:-value]
```

Comment: `lst2 + lst[-4:]`?

Comment: @G_M, Yeh, I'm trying to explain some logic to OP. Obviously there are better ways.

Comment: I understand, just wanted to mention it. If OP is confused by a step, I'm not sure how much easier it will be to understand your example code. Also, maybe a more idiomatic for loop example without using range could help.

Comment: @G_M, Point noted, I've added extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With accessing element in list you can do it by slicing

```
    lst=[201, 303, 210, 407, 213, 313]
lst2=[302,304,404]
lst2.append(lst[2:])
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst=[201, 303, 210, 407, 213, 313]
lst2=[302,304,404]
value=4
for i in lst[-4:]:
    lst2.append(i)
    lst.remove(i)
```

**Output:**

```
[201, 303]
[302, 304, 404, 210, 407, 213, 313]
```